# Permission denied while using aws s3 cp command in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to upload a file to aws s3 bucket in a Jenkins pipeline shell script step.

I am running Jenkins on an aws ec2 instance. I have the s3 access key and secret key configured in Jenkins plugin configuration.  I have tried using aws s3 cp command, s3upload, and s3 sync.  I can run the commands from the linux shell terminal successfully.

These are the commands I have tried so far:

````
/root/.local/bin/aws s3 cp some-document_*.html s3://mybucket/staging/document-folder/ --include "some-document*.html"

/root/.local/bin/aws s3Upload acl: 'Private', bucket: 'mybucket', cacheControl: '', excludePathPattern: '', file: 'some-document*.html', includePathPattern: 'some-document*.html', metadatas: [''], path: 'staging/document-folder/', sseAlgorithm: '', workingDir: '$WORKSPACE/docs/markdown/'```

/root/.local/bin/aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket/staging/document-folder/ --include "some-document*.html"
````

When I run these commands from the command line, I am able to see some-document in mybucket on the aws management console. When I run the Jenkins pipeline I get

```
[2019-03-27T18:25:08.052Z] + /root/.local/bin/aws s3 cp some-document.html s3://mybucket/staging/document-folder --include 'some-document*.html' --profile jenkins

[2019-03-27T18:25:08.052Z] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project_folder@tmp/durable-60152ab5/script.sh: line 5: /root/.local/bin/aws: Permission denied

script returned exit code 1
```

Comment: I think the system user under which jenkins is running the command does not have permission to run the command. Something like using `sudo` perform this command.

Answer (score 2):

Worked with Steven Deals @ Cloudbees and we figured out that I was pointing to the wrong path for the aws command. The correct command is /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp filename s3://mybucket/path/dir --include filename*.html